# Blocking access to local HTML content

Tags: html, block, offline

wondering if you can help point me in the right direction on a bit of a challenge.

I'm building out a few fairly basic HTML pages that will be downloaded for offline use on laptops. I want to be able to make it so that after 14 days, the people that downloaded that HTML content can no longer access it.

Does someone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Regular Dell laptops most likely running Windows 7.. but others may be possible. It's not really set in stone.

Comment: Even if you had a system so the original HTML cannot be viewed, what's to stop people from cutting and pasting the content into another file? What are you trying to accomplish, anyway?

Comment: For super savvy users it's ok if they're able to "hack" it. I just want to be able to implement some sort of mechanism after the 14 days that at least indicates that content "expired" and shouldn't be viewed any longer.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in HTML itself that would allows this.  In order to accomplish it, you'd need to create an application that wrapped/locked the HTML, as well as rendered it.  This is easy enough to do on OS X/Windows.  Each will need their own code, especially since you'll either have to leverage a system component to do the rendering, or you'll need to ship an entire rendering system (say, Webkit) in the app.  The former is certainly simpler.

As with any non-network clock-based mechanism, the protections you'd get would be fairly easily defeatable.

All in all, this does require 'real' development and, IMO, isn't a task to take on lightly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, John. Just as a follow-up, are you saying I could utilize some sort of adobe air type of desktop application to achieve this? Just want to understand what kind of "application" you are recommending.

Comment: Generally speaking, I mean an executable.  Like, Word or iTunes.  You could use Adobe Air to create something application-like, but this does have its caveats (users must install the Adobe Air runtime; unless you encrypt the contents, the HTML is *extremely* easy to pull out; etc).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. HTML is a data format. You cannot make it self-destruct any more than you can make plain text self-destruct.